# Matplotlib scatterplot with different colors from red to blue

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array (x,y,z) with x=1,2,...,100, y=1,2,...,100 and z with 100 values from [0,1]. Now I need to color the points (x,y) in dark red for the value of z near 0 and in dark blue for the value of z near 1. And in between it should go from dark red to light red then to white then to light blue then to dark blue. Can somebody please give me some advice?

Comment: In the end I need it for all values (x,y) from [1,...,100]x[1,...,100], but this is not the point. I don't know how to plot points with specific colors defined by numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> dark red for the value of z near 0 and in dark blue for the value of z near 1. And in between it should go from dark red to light red then to white then to light blue then to dark blue

Looking at [the list of available colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html), this seems to be `RdBu`.

So here's an example scatterplot using `RdBu` with 100 random x, y and z values, where x and y range from 1 to 100 and z from 0 to 1:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 100
x = np.random.randint(1, 100 + 1, n)
y = np.random.randint(1, 100 + 1, n)
z = np.random.random(n)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap="RdBu")
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure 1]